# Not getting accelerometer and heart rate data when screen is turned off in watchOS 2

Tags: accelerometer, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2, healthkit

I'm working on apple watch app using CMMotionManager and HKWorkoutSession to get both the accelerometer and the heart rate data. The app works fine for a short period of time (70 seconds), but when the screen is turned off, both the heart rate and the accelerometer data just stops.

My question is how could I get a 5 minutes data from both the accelerometer and the heart rate sensors?

Comment: Are you initiating an HKWorkoutSession? That's the only way to continue collecting data when the screen goes off.

Answer (score 5):

To take more time when app is going to background you can use `performExpiringActivityWithReason`. This is described here https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/228/?time=345 On my watch it just takes approx 30 seconds

```
NSProcessInfo.processInfo().performExpiringActivityWithReason("Reason") {
   expired in
   if !expired {
      let delay: Int64 = 30
      let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
      dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, delayTime)
   } else {
      dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
   }
}
```

Comment: It's a kind of hack not a viable solution at all and you just get some plus seconds extra then the process will be killed by the system.

Answer (score 4):

Since the release of watchOS 2, HKWorkoutSession is the only way to keep an app running when the watch screen goes off. HOWEVER, the app is in a suspended state. Timers and any other process execution is paused until the screen turns back on. Memory allocations for the app however is preserved. During the time the app is suspended, the device's hardware is still collecting data and storing it on the watch's hard drive. When the screen turns back on the the app come out of suspension and any data that was collected by the hardware is returned at that point to the app (assuming the appropriate listeners were subscribed to).

There is not currently a way to continue to send heart rate data (or any data) from the watch to an iPhone after the screen turns off.

Comment: That's the correct answer. Even CMSensorRecorder could collects data in the background it works with some minutes delay which is not acceptable as a real time data collection as targeted in the question. Actually this and some other limitations are the reason why the AppleWatch is one of the first and biggest failure after the Job era.

Answer (score 1):

watchOS 2 does not allow apps to run while the screen is off.  Although there are ways you can get a bit of extra time, such as with `performExpiringActivityWithReason`, there is no way to ensure that your app runs for a full 5 minutes.

Comment: How can RunKeeper manage to track a run without the phone present? There must be a way to ensure location and heart rate monitoring for extended periods of time.

Comment: With the HKWorkoutSession class in HealthKit.  HealthKit will continue collecting data on behalf of your app, even when your app is not running.  When your app does get an opportunity to run, HealthKit will deliver the data that has been accumulated to your application's active queries.

Answer (score 1):

Now, Apple open an API for recording your Accel data Click:[CMSensorRecorder](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMSensorRecorder_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016255)
. whenever your app is suspended or killed, the API will continuous run in 50Hz almost 3 days.

Comment: It's not real time, it takes roughly 3 minutes delay to get data.

Comment: watchOS 3.0 has improved it so that there's only a few seconds of delay. The 3 minutes delay applies to watchOS 2.0.

Comment: @brunobowden Even you are true theoretically, as this is the communicated delay officially for watchOS 3 (I wrote it before watchOS 3 anyway), we never could reach even similar short time delay in working app on device.

Comment: One more problem which is confused in the answers. Even the CMSensorRecorder runs as a "background" system process with a dedicated function (recordAccelerometerForDuration:) just for this service, it's not real time as it runs till the duration elapsed and then it's available for processing. The heart rate collection doesn't have the same function. It has to run as a simple foreground function with a queue with the possibility that the app (as a HKWorkout app) could go to the background, and meantime delivers the heart rate data continuously in real time.